# OpenXml.WordProcessing.Justification always comes as OpenXmlUnknownElement

Tags: .net, ms-office, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm building a table using OpenXml and setting the Justification property for every cell. It doesn't really matter where I assign this property, either in the Run element or as a TableCellProperty, when the document is open using the Productivity Tool for MS Office the Justification element always comes as `OpenXmlUnknownElement`.
This is an example:

```
TableCell tc = new tbl.TableCell();
tc.Append(new tbl.TableCellProperties(new tbl.Justification() { Val = tbl.JustificationValues.Right }));
```

The text is justified but when converting the docx file into pdf, the justification is gone, and I guess because of this `OpenXmlUnknownElement` issue.

**Edit:**
The problem I have is that when setting the `Justification` property on the `ParagrahProperties` for the paragraph, it doesn't make the alignment. It only works if the `ParagrahProperties` is a direct child of `TableCell`:

```
tc.AppendChild<tbl.ParagraphProperties>(paragraphProperties);
```

But then I get a `OpenXmlUnknownElement`. If I append the properties directly to the paragraph I don't get the `OpenXmlUnknownElement` but it doesn't make the aligment at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation. `TableCellProperties` doesn't take the a `Justification` element. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablecellproperties%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If you are trying to align elements within a cell, you need to put it into `ParagraphProperties`.

Comment: The direct order is table->tableRow->tableCell->paragraph->paragraphProperties. This will work. I don't think you are appending stuff in right order. `new Table(new TableRow(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(new Justification() {blah})))))`. I don't see where you define `paragraphProperties`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I had the Run added before the ParagrahProperties in the Paragraph